# Multiple HTTP Requests on Rest API

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I wrote a function that gets an observable list of pokemon from the pokeapi.co API. If I want to use this function (getPokemons()), I need to subscribe to it. However the subscribe response returns an empty list, because in my function I do another API call using the subscribe function.

The internet clarified that subscribing within a http request is a common mistake, and that you need to use forkMap, flatMap, switchMap, mergeMap or whatever. Unfortunately, I do not understand how I can apply one of those functions to my case.

```
getPokemons(pageNumber: number) : Observable<Pokemon[]> {
    var apiUrl = `${this.apiRoot}?&limit=${this.itemCount}&offset=${pageNumber * this.itemCount - (20)}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${apiUrl}`).pipe(
      map(res => {
        var results: Pokemon[] = [];
        for (let pokemon of res.results) {
          this.getPokemonByName(pokemon.name).subscribe(data => {
            results.push(data);
          },
          err =>  {
            console.error(err.error || 'API error');
          });
        }
        return results;
      })
    );
  }

getPokemonByName(name: string) : Observable<Pokemon> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Pokemon>(`${this.apiRoot}/${name}`).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return new Pokemon(res);
      })
    );
  }
```

In my scenario the original http.get() responds with a list that only has the name of the pokemon. I need to do another API call to get the details of a specific pokemon. Because getPokemonByName().subscribe() is async, the array 'results' stays empty.

I hope you understand my issue, and you can help me figure out how to work this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make use of `forkJoin` like this -

```
getPokemons(pageNumber: number) : Observable<Pokemon[]> {
    var apiUrl = `${this.apiRoot}?&limit=${this.itemCount}&offset=${pageNumber * this.itemCount - (20)}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${apiUrl}`)
               .pipe(
                      switchMap(res => {

                        //now you want to call getPokemonByName for each of the result your got in res.results
                        //so first create an array from getPokemonByName -
                        const observables$ = res.result.map(pokemon => this.getPokemonByName(pokemon.name));
                        return forkJoin(observables$);                        
                      })
                    );
  }

  getPokemonByName(name: string) : Observable<Pokemon> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Pokemon>(`${this.apiRoot}/${name}`).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return new Pokemon(res);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Now your consumer of `getPokemons` should subscribe to the observable returned by `getPokemons`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for. Is their a way to sort the list based on id or do I sort in the consumer (page.ts)?

Comment: you can use `array.sort()` method by using pipe() on forkJoin observable. Like this - `return forkJoin(observables$).pipe(map(joined) => joined.sort((a, b) => a.Id - b.Id))`. See array.sort object sort in - https://www.sitepoint.com/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/

Comment: `Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Pokemon[]>'.
[ng]   Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Pokemon[]'.
[ng]     Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Pokemon'.
[ng]       Property 'id' is missing in type '{}'.` I now get this error in ionic serve. The error is for the line where you return this.httpClient.get<any> in getPokemons()

Comment: fixed it with typecasting `const observables$ = <Pokemon[]> res.results.map(pokemon => this.getPokemonByName(pokemon.name));`

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed simplify your `getPokemons()` method with RxJS operators, such as [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). `forkJoin()` will for the `for..of` loop to be completed before returning all the observables. If you are familiar with the usage of Promises in JavaScript, it is actually similar to `Promise.all`.

Once you have subscribed to it, you will be able to get the return values. And do not forget to import your required operators into your component!

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
.
.
getPokemons(pageNumber: number): Observable < Pokemon[] > {
  const apiUrl = `${this.apiRoot}?&limit=${this.itemCount}&offset=${pageNumber * this.itemCount - (20)}`;
  const observablesList = [];

  return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${apiUrl}`).pipe(
    map(res => {
      const observablesList = [];
      for (let pokemon of res.results) {
        observablesList.push(this.getPokemonByName(pokemon.name));
      }
      return forkJoin(observablesList);
    })
  ).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    // do the rest here
  })
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to return something, I think the observablesList. I now get `Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Pokemon[]>'.`

Comment: Oh yeah thanks for pointing that out! You will need to `return forkJoin(observablesList)`. I have edited it